# Promise inside async

Tags: node.js, async.js

I am writing a code using Node.js. I want to parse JSON array, retrieve elements from JSON array, make db call and assign values to JSON array. Make this complete operation in synchronous way. For this I wrote code using `for` loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if(items[i].type === 'PickSimple'){
        operation(item.searchSpec)
        .then(lov => {
            items[i].listOfValues = lov;
        })
        .catch(err =>{
            console.log(err);
        });
    }   
}

console.log("Final OBJ : "+items)

function operation(lov) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Listofvalue.find({type: lov}, function(err, listofvalues) {    
        if (err) {
            return reject(err);    
        } 
        return resolve(listofvalues);            
    });
});
```

But node is asynchronous, I am not getting desired result. So I have used `async`:

```
async.each(items,
    function(item,callback) {
        if(item.type === 'PickSimple'){
            operation(item.searchSpec)
            .then(lov => {
                item.listOfValues = lov;                
            }).catch(err =>{
                console.log(err);
            });                 
        }
    }, err => {
        if (err) console.error(err.message);        
    }
);
```

I have also tried using `async.forEachOf`.
Still I am not getting desired result. Is anything missing?

EDIT

```
async function processArr(items){
    console.log("Inside processArr "+JSON.stringify(items));
    for(const item in items){
        console.log("Inside for loop, item : "+item);
        if(item.type === 'PickSimple'){
            var listOfValues = await operation(item.searchSpec)
            item.listOfValues = listOfValues;
        }  
    }
    console.log("ProcessArr Final OBJ : "+JSON.stringify(items));
}
```

Output:

```
Inside processArr [{"name":"Call Related To","type":"PickSimple","searchSpec":"TM_CALL_RELATED_TO_SERVICE"},{"name":"Disposition Codes","type":"Text","searchSpec":""},{"name":"VOC 1","type":"Text","searchSpec":""}]
Inside for loop, item : 0
Inside for loop, item : 1
Inside for loop, item : 2
```

Comment: async each will let you loop through your records in synchronous way but inside you're calling another promise. So it won't wait for that and you won't get your desired result.

Comment: @parth, Yes.. this is the problem, But i am not able to solve it. Can you provide some samples? or any workaround

Comment: I think you shouldn't perform a query inside loop. So that's first. And based on your program i suggest that you should first contain array of values that have value 'PickSimple'. Then in callback you can directly perform $in query

Comment: None of your examples is synchronous. In the first one you’re using promises, which are asynchronous, the other uses async, so also asynchronous. Your for loop is certainly imperative synchronous code, but your `then` callbacks are asynchronously resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running Node 8.x+ you can use the `async`/`await`. The following `for...in` should await for promise to complete before iterating to next item.

PS. I've not tested that method, let me know if it works for you.

```
async function processArr(items){
    for(const item in items){
        if(items[item].type === 'PickSimple'){
            var listOfValues = await operation(items[item].searchSpec)

            items[item].listOfValues = listOfValues;

        }  
    }

    console.log("Final OBJ : "+items)
}
```

EDIT:

You're getting undefined because you're calling `console.log` inside `console.log`.

Comment: await operation().then() ? I think you meant `item.listOfValues = await operation(item.searchSpec)`

Comment: @YoukouleleY My bad. Quick copy & paste fail.

Comment: yeah that's better ;)

Comment: Just to clarify, `async/await` won’t make the code synchronous. This is pretty much syntactic sugar for what can already be defined manually with asynchronous promises.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo yep, `Listofvalue.find()` callback will always be asynchronous whatever we do

Comment: @Adriani6 , async function processArr(items){
    console.log("Inside processArr "+JSON.stringify(items));
    for(const item in items){
        console.log("Inside for loop, item : "+console.log(item)); I am getting item value as undefined inside for loop.

Comment: Show me how you called the `processArr`. You need to pass the array into that function. Also please don't put code into comments, it's very hard to read. Also you're doing console.log inside console.log.

Comment: @vishal Like I said, you have console.log inside console.log... this second one causes `undefined`.

Comment: perhaps because items is an array, you'd need to access by `items[item].type`, etc

Comment: @vishal If you knew how arrays work, you'd know that's an index of the item (position in the array), see the updated example... As I said I didn't test the script, so there were errors, but I didn't think you need a guide all the way to accessing properties in the array by their index.. Anyway.

Comment: @Adriani6, Thanks for solving problem